# How to mock $http.post method that has been called in other service method in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I have and angular service that I want to test. In one of his methods I am using $http of angular service. I am simply want to mock that function (to be more specific mock $http.post function) that would return whatever I want and inject this mock to my service test.

I am tried to find solution and  I found $httpBackend but I am not sure that this could help me.

MyService looks like that:

```
angular.module('app').service('MyService' , function (dependencies) {
    let service = this;
    service.methodToTest = function () {
        $http.post('url').then(function () {
            // Do something
        });
    }
}
```

- I am want to test methodToTest and inject the mock of $http.post()

P.S please remember that $http.post() returns promise so I think that I need to consider in that.

Comment: you may want to edit your question title to say that you need help mocking `$http.post`, that seems to be the main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this sounds like exactly what [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) is for.

You might also be able to mock only `$http.post` by doing something like `$http.post = jasmine.createSpy();` if you inject `$http` in your test, but I don't know.

If you do use `$httpBackend`, perhaps this example helps you, in your jasmine test do something like this

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_){
  // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

  $httpBackend.whenRoute('POST', 'url')
    .respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params) {

      expect(somevariable).toContain(params.something);

      return [200, '{"progress":601}'];
    });
}));
```

the `$httpBackend` will intercept all `$http.post`'s to `url` and execute this function. It should be just like the `methodToTest` submitted to the actual `url` and got your fake return value.

The return value indicates a success http status code (200) and returns whatever you put in the second argument as the `data` property of the response (here `response.data == '{"progress":601}'`). Which will be in the `then` function. See [How do I mock $http in AngularJS service Jasmine test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509431/how-do-i-mock-http-in-angularjs-service-jasmine-test)

The `expect` function there is just an example (not needed), to show you that you can put an `expect` clause there if you want.

Comment: Just to be sure. What the expect function does in this method? (what is the purpose of this statement?). And this `return [200, '{"progress":601}'];` is what will be returned to the `then` function?

Comment: I answered your questions by updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> P.S please remember that `$http.post()` returns promise so I think that I need to consider in that.

The service needs to return that promise:

```
angular.module('app').service('MyService' , function (dependencies) {
    let service = this;
    service.methodToTest = function () {
        //$http.post('url').then(function () {
        //vvvv RETURN http promise
        return $http.post('url').then(function () {
            // Do something
        });
    }
}
```

When a function omits a `return` statement, it a returns a value of `undefined`. There is no way that the service can indicate success or failure to the user.